# Symfony 2.7 Doctrine don't mount query correctly

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.7

I'm trying to get the classrooms from a teacher in a many to many relation.

```
$classrooms = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Classroom')->findBy(array('teachers' => $teacher));
```

But I get the error.
The doctrine is not mounting the join:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.institution_id AS institution_id_3 FROM classroom t0 WHERE classroom_teacher.teacher_id = ?' with params [4]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'classroom_teacher.teacher_id' in 'where clause'

But I'm using the many to many

**Class Classroom**

```
/**
 * Classroom
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ClassroomRepository")
 */
class Classroom
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Teacher", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="classrooms")
     */
    private $teachers;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->teachers         = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**Class Teacher**

```
/**
 * Teacher
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TeacherRepository")
 */
class Teacher implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Classroom", mappedBy="teachers")
     */
    protected $classrooms;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->classrooms           = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add this `@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)` and do a :
 `php app/console doctrine:schema:update  --force` to update so that it can take effect.

```
 /**
   * Classroom
   *
   * @ORM\Table()
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ClassroomRepository")
   */
   class Classroom{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Teacher", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="classrooms")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)// this line was missing 
     */
    private $teachers;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->teachers         = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    }
```

Good luck

Comment: No. I'ts not the problem =( I try this with migrations: app/console doctrine:migrations:diff and nothing. No changes detected in your mapping information.

Answer (score 0):

->findBy does not work for many to many relation.

I needed to create an function in the repository:

```
class ClassroomRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getTeachers($id)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $qb->join('c.teachers', 'ct')
           ->where($qb->expr()->eq('ct.id', $id));
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```